# Is there any Algorithm for converting Image of sound to sound?

Tags: image, algorithm, audio

So I have an image like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [bytearray.org](https://www.bytearray.org/wp-content/pics/wave-form.png))</sub>

Is there any algorithm to extract (get as PCM) sound from which was created that image?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basic answer is yes.. sort of. But not from that exact picture. That is because that picture is an extremely time-compressed waveform of the sound. There are likely sound waves missing in that picture hidden between 1 pixel and the next.

In case you're wondering the algorithm is:

```
sound_amplitude=((pixel_height-(image_height/2))/image_height)*sound_resolution
```

where sound_resolution is 128 if 8 bit and 32768 if 16 bit.

But, as I said, that image is too compressed. You have multiple pixels squished into a single vertical line. You can't correctly extract pixel_height form that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the resolution of that image is too low to extract useful information. If you had a greatly zoomed-in version you could convert the pixel data back to audio.

Answer (score 2):

Given sufficient precision, I'm quite sure it's possible. However, I believe this wave would be much too imprecise to allow for any good to come out of it.

Answer (score 2):

To completely recover 1 second of sound at a sampling rate of, say, 44100 Hz; you need to zoom the drawing to be 44100 pixels (approx 40 screens) width.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to zoom in close enough to see the actual waveform, like this:
[image]

Comment: And he would have to sample the curve with at least the same sample rate as the original wave. Otherwise he would get an aliased version of the original wave.